# Column wise selection in SWT Table

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Using **SWT.FULL_SELECTION** in the TableViewer I am able to select the multiple cells in SWT Table. But I instead of selecting the entire row, I want to select column wise just like behavior in MS-Excel. It it possible to somehow implement it in SWT Table/TableViewer?

Comment: No, this isn't supported. I don't use it by maybe Eclipse [NatTable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) has this, check their documentation

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible with the native SWT Table. Check NatTable which is a "super" Table/Tree